# PR2 rqt_plot has the error TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class

Tags: pr2, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a publisher `in PR2's computer` to publish message whose type is  "beginner_tutorials/Num" on topic "/chatter2". Then I want to plot the data from this topic. I cannot use rqt_plot in PR2's computer because it does not support graphics. So I open a terminal in my own computer(which of course supports graphics) and export ROS_MASTER_URI=`[PR2 computer's address]` so that I can communicate with PR2's roscore.  In this local terminal, I use rqt_plot to plot the data like: `rqt_plot  /chatter2/data`, but there is an error:

```
TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class for topic type "beginner_tutorials/Num" on topic "/chatter2"
```

It seems that rqt_plot cannot subscribe to the topic.  But curiously, indeed I can "rostopic list" this topic in the same terminal. So how to let rqt_plot subscribe successfully to the topic and plot my data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191490/pr2-rqt_plot-has-the-error-topiccompleter.update_topics():-could-not-get-message-class/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the answer now. If I want rqt_plot to subscribe to the topic /chatter2 in my local terminal, I have to get the package in my local computer and 'rosmake' it so that my local computer has the definition of the message type of the topic.

That is to say, I should put the package in my local computer's workspace, source my workspace and then run 'rosmake' in the package directory. After that, rqt_plot can plot the data got from this topic.

---

Originally posted by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) with karma: 180 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2019-03-27**:
ROS won't eat unless there's source on everything!